# Access Error 3443: Unrecognized database format 'databasename.mdb'

Tags: ms-access

What could be the cause of the above error when trying to use an MDB file from a VB app?

The access version of the MDB file is 6.68.

I have a feeling this might have been caused by someone trying to open the .mdb file from a newer version of Access and it may have corrupted the MDB.

How can this problem be solved?

Comment: 6.68 is not a version I am familiar with - Access 95 is version 6, Access 2010 is 14. Do you have a more familiar version number (http://bytes.com/topic/access/answers/201416-determine-mdb-files-access-version-without-opening) ? You might also like to add a little code to show how the file is being opened.

Comment: What version is Access 97? because I think it might be that.  I am getting the version number from a small third-party utility I downloaded.

Comment: A97 is version 8. I would have expected A95 to be version 7. But those numbers are independent of the database engine version. A95 used Jet 3.0, A97, 3.5 and 3.51. I'm not sure that there were distinct differences between an A95 file and an A97 file except in VBA-related issues. That is, if all you're using is pure Jet objects (tables/queries), there isn't going to be a difference. But certainly 6.68 is not a version number that means anything in any context, Access or Jet.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some VBScript which, hopefully, will get a version for you. Save this in an ordinary text file with a vbs extension and drag and drop an mdb onto it. This is a very quick sketch, and only roughly tested.

```
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If WScript.Arguments.Count > 0 Then
    sPath = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
Else
    sPathTemp = Left(WScript.ScriptFullname, _
        InStrRev(WScript.ScriptFullname, "\"))

    sPath = InputBox("Enter Path and Name of .mdb", "Get Ver", sPathTemp)
End If

If sPath = "" Or fs.FileExists(sPath) = False _
    Or Right(sPath, 4) <> ".mdb" Then

    MsgBox "Not a valid file: " & vbCrLf & sPath, 64, "Get Ver" 
Else

    Set cnnDB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    cnnDB.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
    cnnDB.Mode = 1 ''adModeRead

    On Error Resume Next
    cnnDB.Open sPath

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
         MsgBox "Error"
    Else
        MsgBox "4 = Access 97, 5 = Access 2000 (2002?)" & vbcrlf & _
        "Value for " & sPath & " is: " & _
        cnnDB.Properties.Item("Jet OLEDB:Engine Type").Value
        cnnDB.Close
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

"Unrecognized Database Format" errors are typical of corruption, though they are also associated with opening a database with an older version of Access that was created in a newer version of Access (or possibly, in your case, with a connection string that references an older version of Jet).

According to the [Access Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Access), there's no such thing as Version 6.68.  Not for Access and not for Jet, so you're going to need to figure out which version you have and then determine which version of Jet you need to make the connection.

Note that if you are using Access 2007, an accde or mde created in Access 2007 SP1 can't be read in Access 2007 without installing the SP.

If it does turn out to be corruption, I would encourage you to create a new, fresh DB in a different folder.  Import the tables, queries, forms, etc... into the new DB, perform a Compact and Repair, and then test the new DB to ensure it is free from corruption.